# Как реализовать реакцию на команду с опечаткой Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Занимаюсь разработкой бота на питоне уже около полугода и есть одна проблема.
Допустим есть команда /дем. Зачастую кто-нибудь пишет /деи и бот из-за опечатки никак на команду не реагирует.

Как можно реализовать реакцию программы на команды с опечатками? Просто подбором я думаю не вариант, команд много, соответственно проверка каждой таким образом будет много есть.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Идея заключается в том, чтоб найти степень похожести строки с командами, которые бот поддерживает. Наиболее похожую команда (если различия не превышают какого-то разумного порога подобранного экспериментально) можно использовать или предложить пользователю в качестве замены или подсказки.

В качестве степени похожести часто используют количество операций, которые нужно сделать, чтоб превратить одну строку в другую. Есть [разные метрики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric), которые отличаются тем, какие операции допустимы.

Часто используют [расстояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0), где допустимы замены, удаления и добавления символов.

Еще используют, как указали в комментарии, [расстояние Хэмминга](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A5%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0). Тут допустимы только замены символов.