# Нахождение похожего слова в тексте

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть текст. Предположим, он будет состоять из одного предложения, хотя это не особо важно.

`text = "Привет, меня зовут Ат0н"`

и у меня есть список слов, которые нужно найти в тексте

`list = ["Вася", "Петя", "Антон", "Вова"]`

Но в тексте у нас не Антон, а Ат0н.
Возможно ли обнаружить похожее слово?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance, https://pythoninoffice.com/how-to-find-similar-strings-using-python/

Comment: Так же как и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1292950/218971). Разбиваете текст на слова, для каждого ищете "похожее" используя выбранную метрику расстояния. Если слово ближе чем определенная величина (нужно ее подобрать экспериментально, в зависимости от приемлемой степени похожести), то считаем его похожим.

Answer (score 0):

Вот идея как такое можно реализовать, функция разбивает предложение на слова, а потом сверяет их со словами в списке, и выписывает похожие слова. Я установил погрешность в два символа, и теперь он выводит в списке похожие слова в таком порядке: 
`[[оригинал, найденное], [оригинал, найденное]]`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

lst = ["Вася", "Петя", "Антон", "Вова"];
text = "Привет, меня зовут Ат0н";

def check_text(input_text, check_list):
    input_text = input_text.decode('utf-8');
    result = [];
    
    for word in input_text.split(" "):
        wrd = {};
        for i in word:
            for n in check_list:
                n = n.decode('utf-8');
                for l in n:
                    if (i == l):
                        try: wrd[n].append(0);
                        except: wrd[n] = [0,];
        for key in wrd.keys():
            if (len(wrd[key]) > len(word)-2) and \
                (len(wrd[key]) <= len(word)):
                result.append([word, key]);
                      
    return result;
    
check_list = check_text(text, lst);
# check_list = [["Ат0н", "Антон"]];

print(check_list[0][0]);
print(check_list[0][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю поискать на pypi.org запрос "similar text". К примеру модуль similar_text вычисляет похожесть слов в процентах

```
>>> from similar_text import similar_text
>>> similar_text('luosicheng', 'lsc')
46
>>> similar_text('lsc', 'luosicheng')
46
```

Так как из условий вопроса не ясен какой вариант нужен в следующем случае:
text='Привет вася воблу взял'
list['ася','бася']