# Бот-модератор пропускает символы в комментариях

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Бот-модератор удаляет комментарии при совпадении слов в словаре.

```
async def mess_handler(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text.lower()
       if str(message.from_user.id) != cfg.ADMIN_ID:
        for word in cfg.WORDS:
            if word in text:
                await message.delete()
```

Однако, пропускает спам-комментарии с указанными ниже символами в словах. Их добавление в словарь не помогает.

[image: скрин pycharm]

Подскажите, что это за символы в словах и как с ними бороться?

"ρᴀсπροсτpaняйтe", "эτи", "ужacныᧉ", "κᴀдpы", "вᴏ," "евpᴏпейcᴋuх", "чτoбы", "видeлu", "ᴋοмy", "πᴏмᴏгᴀюꚍ", "тбиτыe", "πᴏймали", "πᴏльсᴋyю", "нᴀᧉмнuцy", "жᧉсꚍκᴏ", "нᧉй", "пᴩедвᴀρuтельнο", "вывeзя", "лᧉс", "Οнᴀ", "κτo", "таᴋиᧉ", "уκpᴏпы", "сᴀмᴏм", "дeлᧉ", "связывaꚍься", "быcτρᴏ", "ρазлᧉτeлuсь", "тᧉлeгρаму", "пoсмοтρeτь", "бᧉз", "цᧉнзγpы", "тγꚍ", "ᴏ", "τ", "Сᴩᴏчнᴏ", "pᴀсπρoсτpaнuтe", "эτи", "ужᴀсные", "ᴋaдpы", "ᧉx", "евρoпᧉйcких", "Oꚍбиꚍыe", "пᴏймᴀли", "πᴏльсκую", "наeмницγ", "жеcꚍκο", "надpγгᴀлuсь", "пpᧉдвapительнο", "вывᧉзя", "лᧉс", "uзбuв", "зналᴀ", "ктo", "ꚍaκиᧉ", "укρoπы", "cамoм", "дeле", "нuмu", "связываꚍься", "Kадpы", "бысτᴩᴏ", "pᴀзлᧉτᧉлись", "πᴏ", "вcᧉмy", "ꚍᧉлегρамy", "Пοcмᴏτpᧉꚍь", "цензyᴩы", "Эτa", "сᴋaꚍuнᴀ", "пοймᴀна", "нашuмu", "бᴏйцами", "пᴩи", "шꚍγᴩме", "γκρᧉπᴀ"

Comment: Да, проблема интересная. Попробуйте поиск по маске без одного-двух символов. Других вариантов, боюсь, нет.

Comment: поиск по маске - это как?

Comment: Ну, формируешь список регулярок типа '?ри' 'п?и' 'пр?' и прогоняешь при поиске через него.

Comment: Нашел еще похожий вопрос, [можете посмотреть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1334884/Нахождение-похожего-слова-в-тексте).

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку!