# Добавить в код бота модерацию по языку и символам

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Бот-модератор удаляет комментарии в ТГ-канале, содержащие мат на русском языке. Не понимаю, какой код  добавить, чтобы удалял нежелательные комментарии со словами с заменой русских букв на иную кодировку, буквы любых других языков, цифры или символы. В частности, постоянно появляется вот этот комментарий, и добавление в словарь вариаций "фото" и "видосики" не помогает.[image: пример]

Код:

```
import logging, re
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import config as cfg

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token=cfg.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

async def mess_handler(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text.lower()
    if str(message.from_user.id) != cfg.ADMIN_ID:
        for word in cfg.WORDS:
            if word in text:
                await message.delete()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Ну, совсем недавно точно такой же вопрос видел. Сейчас кину ссылку.

Comment: Вот [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1546246/Бот-модератор-пропускает-символы-в-комментариях). Похоже, это дубликат. Тревогу пока не ставил, если этот вопрос чем-то отличается, объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: В том вопросе были иные символы и проблема. В данном случае, алфавит, похоже, русский.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте регулярные выражения.

Импортируем `re`:

```py
import re
```

Теперь давайте составим список нежелательных слов:

```py
words = ["видео", "реклама", "спам"]
```

Объявим символы замены:

```py
letters = {
    "а": ["a"], # английская a
    "о": ["o", "0"], # английская о
    ...
}
```

И теперь превращаем words в список регулярок:

```py
def convert(word):
    for letter in lettersList:
        word = word.replace(letter, f'({letter}|{"|".join(lettersList[letter])})')
    return word

wordRegexes = list(map(convert, words))

# wordRegexes == ['виде(о|o|0)', 'рекл(а|a)м(а|a)', 'сп(а|a)м']
```

Для того, что бы проверить, является ли слово запрещённым мы просто проходимся по каждой регулярке и применяем её к слову:

```py
def validate(text):
    for wordRegex in wordRegexes:
        if re.search(wordRegex, text):
            return False
    return True
```

Пример:

```py
print(validate("Какая либо фраза"))
print(validate("Какая либо фраза со словом виде0"))
```

Полный код:

```py
import re;

words = ["видео", "реклама", "спам"]

lettersList = {
    "а": ["a"], # английская a
    "о": ["o", "0"] # английская о
}

def convert(word):
    for letter in lettersList:
        word = word.replace(letter, f'[{letter}|{"|".join(lettersList[letter])}]')
    return word

wordRegexes = list(map(convert, words))

def validate(text):
    for wordRegex in wordRegexes:
        if re.search(wordRegex, text):
            return False
    return True
    
print(validate("Какая либо фраза"))
print(validate("Какая либо фраза со словом виде0"))
```

Comment: Так, а если неизвестно, во что заменять? Если будет не виде0, а, скажем, виде@? Нет, тут надо реализовать поиск _похожих слов_ и регулярки, подобные тем, которые предлагаете вы не подойдут.

Comment: @Глеб добавить все возможные комбинации в любом случае придётся. Иначе может возникнуть куча ложных срабатываний

Comment: @Глеб А вообще всегда можно обойти защиту) Тут только если нейросети подключать, тот же чатгпт 3.5 (по моим тестам) подходит довольно неплохо

Comment: @Алексей Вариант с нейросетями интересен, есть опыт?)

Comment: @Andrey Вариант с нейросетями платный в любом случае) Либо надо очень много мощностей на обучение и очень много мощностей на сервер

Comment: @Алексей Извините за глупый вопрос, но я совсем начинающий. Не совсем понял, как готовый код, который приводите в ответе, можно вставить в код бота? Код сейчас - в первом сообщении.

Comment: @Andrey Где ни будь объявляете все методы и переменные, после чего используете функцию validate, которая возвращает True или False